# Interactive remote password input for sudo commands not working with Paramiko

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, paramiko

I am trying to come up with an example where I try to use a command which required sudo permissions and try to execute it on a remote server using Paramiko but am unsuccessful. The program and the error message is given below

```
ip = server_hostname
userName = user1
passWord = password1
command = 'sudo hostname'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect(ip, username=userName, password=passWord, port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdin.write('password\n')
stdin.flush()
print stderr.readlines()
```

The error message is as given below:

```
['sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified\n']
```

Is there something I am missing with sudo password entry?

Answer (score 0):

ssh appears somewhat paranoid when it comes to granting the input of a password. But actually the behavior does make sense. It tries to prevent miss use by remote controlling ssh sessions. As a consequence there are two strategies how ssh is able to ask for a password entry:

1. a tty must be allocated for the process, or a pseudo tty. In other words: the session must be an interactive one. Without such tty (terminal), where should ssh ask the password from?
2. the `DISPLAY` environment variable must be set and an "askpass" program must be known to the ssh process, typically it is specified in the environment variable `SSH_ASKPASS`. The value must point to an executable, a helper program, that allows the input of a password in a manner that makes sense for a confidential information like a password. Every system usually has such utilities installed, often different ones for different environments like plain X, GNOME or KDE. In this case ssh will try to use the utility as X application inside the DISPLAY to ask for the password.

Aparently in your situation neither of the two situations is present. That is typically the case when the remote shell is not directly controlled by an interactive session and no askpass helper is installed in the remote side that can be used on a given X display.